# Angular two-way databinding on empty array not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive for a popup bubble, where the buttons to be displayed in the popup are provided in an attribute as an array of objects:

**JS (Controller)**

```
$scope.buttons = [{ label: 'OK' }, { label: 'Cancel' }]
```

The directive looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<ui-popup buttons="buttons"></ui-popup>
```

**JS (Directive)**

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('ui')
    .directive('uiPopup', [function () {

        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: '/uikit/views/ui-popup.html',
            scope: {
                buttons: '=',
                anchor: '@',
                x: '@',
                y: '@'
            },
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                ...
            }
        };
    }]);
```

This works fine. However, what I need is to start with no buttons in the bubble, then add the buttons when an event in the application occurs. So I start with an empty array, and use `$scope.buttons.push(obj)` to add each button. Note I'm maintaining the original array, not replacing the array, so data-binding shouldn't be broken. However, the new button doesn't show up in the bubble, and debugging shows the button isn't added in the directive scope.

After experimenting, I found by chance that if I start with a non-empty array and then add it works just fine. Why does angular data-binding break on an empty array? What can I do to work around the issue?

**Edit**

The event is called on `ng-click` and looks like this:

**JS (Controller)**

```
$scope.onClick = function () {

    $scope.locked = true;
    $scope.buttons.push({ label: 'OK' });
};
```

Comment: How are you binding to events? You might need to use `$scope.$apply()` in your event handler.

Comment: Good suggestion @AnthonyChu. It's from an `ng-click` so an `$apply()` block shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: This is odd that the original length of the array matters. Can you recreate in a fiddle? Distilled my understanding of your problem to this but it seems to work regardless if array is originally empty or not... http://jsfiddle.net/0xnotggr/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/t0qagtc1/ It looks like your example?

Comment: The only theory I had was that an empty arrays might have some memory voodoo going on the prevented binding from working correctly. Bit of a stretch though.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce in fiddle - yours is correct @dizel3d.

Comment: @SimonRobb, can you publish your site?

Comment: Thanks both of you, I've worked out what the problem is, though I don't understand why it isn't working. I'll post an answer below, I'd appreciate your insight as to why what I had wasn't working. @dizel3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive HTML looked like this:

```
...
<div class="buttons" ng-if="buttons">
    <ui-button color="primary" size="small" ng-repeat="button in buttons">{{ button.label }}</ui-button>
</div>
...
```

You can see the buttons in the popup are only shown if `buttons` is truthy. Interestingly, the `div.buttons` wasn't showing when `buttons` was empty, even though `!![]` gives true in javascript, so I can only assume Angular uses its own equality function to test here. However, even when a button was subsequently added to the array, the div wasn't showing.

When I changed the equality to `ng-if="buttons.length"`, (as it probably should have been from the start) things worked correctly.

Comment: Took a quick look at angular's source... It looks like you're right that it uses a custom `toBoolean()` function in 1.2.x to determine truthiness in `ngIf`; and an empty array is considered falsy. Because `ngIf` simply puts a watch on its expression, it's just watching the reference to the array and doesn't detect a change when the array's content changes. What that meant for you is that  `ngIf` evaluated to false with an empty array, and never changed to true when you pushed stuff into it. Looks like the behavior is changed in 1.3.0; an empty array is now truthy in `ngIf`.

Comment: In case you're interested here's the commit that made the change... https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bdfc9c02d021e08babfbc966a007c71b4946d69d

Comment: Ah, great find! Mystery solved, and a good insight into the `ng-if` directive. Thanks for the help!